# How to find Xpath for a dynamic element in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to click on particular "add task" link , when more add tasks are there and I couldn't be able to find an unique Xpath

[image]

In this case the add task comes when we add new project, so every-time new add task generates.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you need to locate the "add tasks" link based on the project name. The project name node is not expanded on the screenshot, but I'm assuming there is an `a` element there too:

```
String projectName = "qrr";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[a = '" + projectName+ "']/following-sibling::td/a[. = 'add tasks']"));
```

This is to locate the "add tasks" button for the `qrr` project name.

Or, you can locate the appropriate row and use "by link text" locator:

```
WebElement row = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td/a = 'qrr']"));
WebElement addTasks = row.findElement(By.linkText("add tasks"));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying alecxe, Actually the condition is the "add task" link gets added with the same name i.e "add tasks" whenever we create new project so the linkText or the Xpath we cant use because it will not select the correct one , as all the project is having the same name for "add task"(refer screen shot). How to locate particular add task for different projects?   .

Comment: The screenshot's resolution is too low. Could you provide us with a better one? Or maybe you could reproduce the HTML in your question.

Comment: @ChandanKumar I'm actually providing a way to locate the "add tasks" *based on the project name*. Isn't it what you are asking about?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula - please zoom it for better view.

Comment: I believe @alecxe answered it.

Comment: @alecxe - the xpath you written for 'qrr' project is hard-coded. in my case when user creates projects , he may give any name on the run time and after that there will be new name for the project that case it will only select qrr project only.

Comment: @ChandanKumar sure, it was just an example. Insert any project name dynamically via string formatting or string concatenation.

Comment: @ChandanKumar but your code will run for test cases, where you know which projects have been and will be created. You need to know the project you're looking for to find a particular "add task" link. If you don't, I just don't get your question, then.

Comment: @alecxe - can u send the sample code for passing string in Xpath ? will be helpful for me

Comment: @ChandanKumar okay, added an example. Hope that helps.

Comment: @ChandanKumar see if it makes sense to accept the answer to close the topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Path but I will suggest to use the CSS Selector inlace of Path. CSS Selectors are faster than Path. To learn CSS Selector you can use http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp .

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked perfectly fine

```
String ProjectName = "qrr";
```

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td/a[contains(text(),'"+ ProjectName +"')]/ancestor::tr[2]/td[2]/a[contains(text(),'add tasks')]")).click();`